# Exporting geodata from QGIS to File Geodatabase

Tags: qgis, export, file-geodatabase

For a project, I need to create a set of vector data that I think I could do in QGIS. However, the customer requires that the final data set needs to be delivered in a Esri File Geodatabase.

Is there a way to export geodata from QGIS into an Esri File Geodatabase?

Answer (score 6):

> This answer was written for version 2x of QGIS.

You can create one off file geodatabases(s) by right clicking on the layer in the Layers TOC>Save As, and change the format type to ESRI FileGDB:

[image]

There does not appear to be a way to export various features classes though to one geodatabase from the GUI.

Alternativly, you could create your separate tables in a SQLite DB within QGIS, and use OSGeo4W Shell (should be installed with your QGIS) using ogr2ogr command line to convert from SQLite to ESRI FileGDB, see example expression below:

```
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" C:/Temp/Temp.gdb C:/Temp/Temp.sqlite
```

Answer (score -1):

save selected faeture as option showns (appear) when shapes are selected on the screen