# Saving Shapefile to File Geodatabase in QGIS 2.2?

Tags: file-geodatabase, qgis-2.2

I searched the StackExchange forum for an answer too my question and apologize if I missed it.

I'm using QGIS 2.2 64-bit and able to read feature classes from an ESRI file geodatabase without a problem.  The problem occurs when I attempt to save a layer to a file geodatabase by right-clicking on the layer and selecting "Save As."  I have "ESRI FileGDB" selected as the desired format and enter a name for the exported feature class.  The result is a file geodatabase created with the name of the feature class and an error message

> Export to vector file failed.
>
> Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Error: Failed at creating
>   FeatureDataset  (General function failure.))

Any idea why the feature class export to a file geodatabase fails?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102189/exporting-geodata-from-qgis-to-esri-file-geodatabase/102190#102190

Answer (score 2):

Writing to a File Geodatabase is not possible by default in QGIS. If you reference the OGR page (which is the list of formats that you are able to use in QGIS) you will see the following:

```
No, needs FileGDB API library
```

I do not use File GDB myself, so I will not be able to assist you any further.  Here is the location of that page:

http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html

Comment: If they're on Windows and using osgeo4w installer, they just need to install the gdal-filegdb package to get _write_ functionality.

Comment: It appears that it *is* possible on some level. This question describes using the same process given as answer in the question I have linked to as a possible duplicate. But it seems they are running into an error when using that method. Perhaps @SaultDon is correct or at least on the right track in that the QGIS installation is incomplete? Now, the answer does state they are one-off geodatabases, not saving to an existing one, but again, that appears to be what asker is doing.